# Why is the sample time for a simulink constant block not "constant"?

Tags: simulink

I have a Constant block with `Sample time = inf` in an otherwise empty model, and when I click `Display/Sample Time/Colors`, it shows the sample time for this block as gray, indicating "Fixed in Minor Step". This is a bit surprising, since there is an extra category for "Constant". Is this expected behavior, and if not, what could I have messed up in my settings?

[image: simulink sample time labelling error]

I first noticed this in a more complex model, where a subsystem with a combination of discrete and constant inputs was labelled "Fixed in Minor Step". According to the 2nd-last line of [this page of mathworks documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/managing-sample-times-in-systems.html), combinations of constant blocks with discrete ones should not be designated as having hybrid sample times.

I am seeing this behavior in both 2014b and 2015a releases on linux.